# unable to handle HTTP 422 with best in place rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript, best-in-place

I have my controller code like this:

```
def update
respond_to do |format|
  if refresh_quantity_in_inventory
    format.json { render json: { message: "Quantity successfully updated" } }
  else
    format.json { render json: @errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
```

end

The CoffeeScript for this is like this:

```
ready = ->
   $('#best_in_place_cart_quantity').best_in_place().bind 'ajax:error', (evt, data, status, xhr) ->
      alert xhr
      alert xhr.status
      if (xhr.status == 422)
        alert("Inventory count is not enough")
$(document).ready ready
$(document).on "page:load", ready
```

I have also tried `ajax:success` but neither triggers the callback. How do I catch 422? What should I do?

---

```
$('#best_in_place_cart_quantity').best_in_place().done((data, status, response) ->
    alert 'Done handler. HTTP code: ' + response.status
    return
  ).fail (error) ->
    alert 'Fail handler. HTTP code: ' + error.status
    return
```

This did not work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the code that finally worked.

```
$('.best_in_place_cart_quantity').best_in_place()

$(".best_in_place_cart_quantity").bind 'ajax:error',  (evt,  data,  status,  xhr) ->
    alert "Not enough quantity"
```

Lesson learnt was that, we should bind best in place fields through class instead of Id.

Answer (score 0):

This example of code show how to handle HTTP errors use JQuery (i.e. 422):

```
$.get('http://httpbin.org/status/422')
    .done(function(data, status, response) {
        alert('Done handler. HTTP code: ' + response.status);
    })
    .fail(function(error) {
        alert('Fail handler. HTTP code: ' + error.status);
    });
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/b1dprmw2/) is snippet of this code.

Try to adopt code above and replace `ready` handler to:

```
$ ->
   // your code here
```